# Deploy java file on a company server

Tags: java, deployment, application-server

I have a java file written in Netbeans IDE on my local pc. I have to deploy this file on the company server.
Basically, this file acts as a listener and it listens to another server that sends out alarms. My program captures these alarms and stores it in sql server database.
Now, to connect to the alarm server, i need to place my file on the company server. my file needs to run (listen) continuously for the alarms. I need to provide my ip address and port number to the alarm server for connection.

I need to know how do i deploy my java file on my company server and keep it running.

thanks.

Comment: Have you gotten it to work on your machine without Netbeans already?

Comment: So.. You're basically asking how to run this file as a "service" in the background of the server-specific platform environment?

Comment: If you expect any help, I suggest you share what is the OS of the server, do you have external dependencies, do you use any build tools, how is this packaged and so on...

Comment: @DerMike: i havent gotten it to work without netbeans. what do you suggest i should do?

Comment: What does company server exactly mean? Is it a application server like WebSphere or tomcat or do you only have a standalone application and are trying to run that?

Comment: @all: :i tried to compile my program using cmd in windows. i included the classpath of the jdbc drivers required too. but it gives me the following error while compiling: Note: csServer.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you do is get the program running on your local workstation (outside of NetBeans); once you have that cracked you have a chance of getting it running on the remote server.

I'm guessing that this is a simple java applicaiton (ie with a class with a **public static void main(String[] args)** method in it). If so fire up the command-prompt, change to the directory in which your Java class sits and compile it using the JDK:

```
javac MyClass.java
```

This will give you a **class** file (ie MyClass.class), that you can then run:

```
java MyClass
```

Once it works, you can copy **MyClass.class** to the server and run it from there in the same way (assuming the server already has a Java Runtime Environment installed).

Hope that points you in the right direction...

Comment: :i tried to compile my program using cmd in windows. i included the classpath of the jdbc drivers required too. but it gives me the following error while compiling:
     Note: csServer.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
     Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.